# Testing in-app purchases

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I want to test in-app purchases in my app on device with different Apple ID(not developer Apple ID). I add device in Apple Developer. But I still can’t  do it. How I test purchases on device with not developer Apple ID?

Comment: Have you solve the issue?

Comment: Then try with different email id.

Answer (score 11):

if you're getting "Unknown Errors while creating Sandbox Tester, Please check Error Log, email=********@*****.****"

**Here's the solution:**

1. some email servers aren't accepted (for example @bk.ru didn't work, @gmail.com accepted);
2. you must use "strong" password (at least 1 capital letter, 1 number and 1 punctuation char);
3. you may not use same email address twice (even if previously removed).

Recommendation (also recommended by Apple): gmail supports "extended" pseudo-addresses you may (and should) use for sandbox users:
pretend you own myname@gmail.com - you may use myname+anythinghere@gmail.com (anything after + sign)

Comment: I got this error also when everything should be fine :/

Comment: For me adding a strong password fixed the issue (my e-mail was a @gmail.com one)

Comment: @Roman86: I tried that and it didn't work. What helped was using Safari for create user. But it didn't help for any email. It's magic.

Comment: @JanVáclavík which browser you tried first time? I use Chrome and it works there

Comment: I still can't get this to work, why is this so incredibly crap?

Comment: @DanielDewhurst hi! Are you using gmail.com address? Make sure you weren't using it already there. Add +1 or +2 etc before @ symbol. And try password like "super-Password11" (at least 1 capital and 1 punctuation and 1 digit). And try using Chrome or Safari.
I've just did it again - user successfully added

Comment: @mailinator.com emails are also produce "Unknown error"

Answer (score 1):

You must create Sandbox Tester Account to test In App Purchase.

Comment: Just use another email address. And this could be a fake email address such as: asdsdfdf@gmail.com.

Comment: It cannot be a fake email address. It must be an email address that you have access to because the test account must be verified by replying to a verification request email.

Comment: yes, but while adding a new tester it says "Unknown Errors while creating Sandbox Tester, Please check Error Log." for email. And I am not able to do any thing after this, tried all the emails

Comment: Yes, add a new tester as an admin and then login with that new admin and try to add as many sandbox testers. If still you are not able to add sandbox testers then add testers as admin.

Comment: Do we need to publish the app as Beta, because i've created a sandbox users and still in-app-purchase dialog doesn't appear to me

Answer (score 0):

For testing In App purchase you must have to use Sandbox Tester Account.

Answer (score 0):

To add any sandbox testers, add a new user as admin and then login to itunes with the new admin account and try to add the sandbox testers. You will be easily add number of sandbox testers. 
Let me know if you are still not able to add sandbox testers.