# IOS In-App-Purchase verify in Developer Account

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

is there a way to check in the apple developer account purchases made by sandbox testers?, this is just to check if the in-app-purchases are working properly

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Testing in-app purchases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478763/testing-in-app-purchases)

Comment: Check "Sandbox Testers" tab in the iTunes Connect/"Users and Roles"

Comment: yes I can see the sandbox testers on Itunes Connect, but I want to know how many in-app-purchases went successful or reject, is there a way to view this on the developer account or itunes connect?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible. You can track data about purchasing by your own and sand it to your server.